# Como fazer Fileupload de vídeo no angular 4?

Tags: angular

Criei uma **API** Java para fazer fileupload de qualquer arquivo, é algo simples, ele simplemente pega qualquer imagem selecionada e envia para C:\imagens, estou usando com Angular 4, meu objetivo é fazer essa implementação com vídeo, mas eu tinha tentado antes com imagens pois são é mais fácil encontrar códigos disponiveis e pronto com implementação de imagens.

Fui fazer com vídeo e não deu certo, acredito que seja algo que devo alterar no meu Front-end Angular. Então veja o código abaixo;

Esse é meu serviço;

```
export class MidiaService {

  midiasUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/midias';


  constructor(private http: Http) { }


  urlUploadAnexo(): string {
    return `${this.midiasUrl}/files`;
}
```

E esse é meu componente:

```
get urlUploadAnexo() {
    return this.midiaService.urlUploadAnexo();
}
```

E essa é minha página:

```
<div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3 ui-fluid">
        <label>URL</label>
        <p-fileUpload name="files" mode="basic" auto="true" maxFileSize="1000000000000000000000000000"
        chooseLabel="Anexar" accept="image/*,application/*"
        [url]="urlUploadAnexo"
    ></p-fileUpload>
      </div>
```

Eu acho que o local onde devo alterar para aceitar arquivos de vídeo deva ser na página, alguém teria uma sugestão como deve fazer a alteração? por favor!

Comment: `<p-fileUpload>` não é uma *tag* HTML5. Pode especificar qual *framework* você está utilizando?

Comment: e pode também explicar melhor o que não deu certo